# Getting first singular values

Tags: python, matrix

I have been trying to find the way of getting first and first two singular values of a matrix. But after few ours of researching I thought i could reach out here and get some help on how to find first singular value of matrix.

```
 import numpy.matlib
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.linalg import svd


 def get_singular_values(M, k):

     u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(M, full_matrices=False)

     singular_values = numpy.matrix(u[:, :k]) * numpy.diag(s[:k]) * 
     numpy.matrix(v[:k, :]) #my attempt

     return singular_values


 M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

 only_first_singular_value = get_singular_values(M, 1) #first singular
 print(only_first_singular_value) # 1 is for first singular
 only_first_singular_value = get_singular_values(M, 2) #first two singular
 print(only_first_singular_value) # 2 is for 2 singular
```

Comment: `singular_values` comes out of nowhere and `k` is unused in `get_singular_values`. Please update the example

Comment: k is for number of singulars, and as i mentioned i need some help with the code and i want to return singular value.

Comment: you also mentioned you spent few hours solving this problem. It will be great to see your attempt to spot the error

Comment: i added my attempted code

Comment: as far as I remember all you need is just `return s[:k]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.linalg.svd()` gives you the singular values directly:

```
In [1]: m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])

In [2]: _, s, _ = np.linalg.svd(m)

In [3]: s[0] # first singular value
Out[3]: 25.462407436036397

In [4]: s[1] # second singular value
Out[4]: 1.2906616757612328
```